# Can I use an external GPS receiver by connecting both GPS and Android device to a PC?

Tags: gps, external-gps

I have an HTC One X which I like and carry everywhere, but the GPS is atrocious.  It takes tens of minutes to get a position, loses it easily and it's not even very accurate when it has a signal.  However, I also have a Garmin GPS which is fantastic at gaining and holding a steady and accurate GPS location.  I'd like to use the Garmin as an external GPS in combination with android's mock-location feature, in my car.

It is definitely possible to drive `gpsd` on a pc with the garmin - but I don't know how to use that to provide location data to android.  The phone is already rooted and I'm not averse to hacking it a bit more, but of course simpler solutions are preferred.  Initially I would be happy plugging the Garmin and HTC into a laptop but I'll move to a Raspberry Pi as soon as I know it works.  Not really bothered about using USB OTG to connect as this is for in-car use.

So: Can I use `gpsd` running on a PC to control a mock-location on Android?  If so, how?

Comment: Does your Garmin support Bluetooth, so you could use it as BT GPS mouse? If so, there are easier methods than fiddling with cables and a PC, plus running around with a big rucksack to carry it all.

Comment: No - it's a ForeRunner 205. https://buy.garmin.com/en-GB/GB/sports/discontinued/forerunner-205/prod348.html  Very basic but extremely lightweight, good accuracy and battery life.  BT GPS mice cost, and seeing as I carry the Garmin all the time anyway, seem a bit pointless.

Comment: Besides, I'm really talking about in-car use and I already use the phone's BT to connect to the stereo :)  Not sure if the phone could connect to both stereo and GPS mouse.  To be honest it's pretty flakey with just the stereo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this with your PC. Likely the easiest way would be to hack up a custom script on your PC to respond to new positions coming from gpsd, and use the following command to mock those locations on the phone:

```
adb shell setLatLon latitude longitude
```

You need to have previously turned on USB debugging and mock locations in the phone's settings.

However, this seems unnecessarily complicated. If you search for *external gps* on Google Play, you'll see a zillion apps that allow you to connect your Android device directly to an external GPS receiver. There's no need to involve your PC at all. Try a few and report back which one works best for you.

Comment: Sounds good.  To keep them charged up I usually have the Garmin and phone plugged into a laptop when I'm driving anyway.  So a simple script to scrape GPS data from the Garmin and send it to the phone would really suit my needs perfectly.  I'll see what I can hack up...

Comment: If I search for external GPS on google play, I don't really see anything helpful.  Can you suggest a specific app to check out?

Comment: A tenner will buy you a USB charger that plugs into a lighter socket. If you're looking for an excuse to buy yourself a raspi, find a better one!

Comment: Thanks for your update and indulging me :)  `setLatLon: not found` though :(  This person had the same idea though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729767/setting-android-mock-locations-in-a-script

Comment: While most "external GPS" apps seem to be specifically for BT mice, I've just found [RtkGPS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rtkgps/ru0xdc.rtkgps): high rated, and the desc says USB is supported as well. A second candidate would be [You are here](http://www.appbrain.com/app/you-are-here-gps/com.agbooth.usbgps).